# Can I pocket and cover the Queen in a single strike and win?

Tags: carrom

If I pocket my last C/m and the Queen in a single strike, is this a win or a lose or do you put the pieces in the center again?

Answer (score 3):

"If while shooting for the Queen you also sink one of your pieces, the Queen is automatically covered, no matter which went in first." [Carrom.org](http://carrom.org)

By this rule the game would be won along with the bonus for the Queen.

Comment: What does "covered" mean? Win, lose or retry?

Comment: @ire_and_curses To end/win the game, the Queen must be "covered" (by either player). This means that after pocketing the Queen, you take another shot. If you don't pocket one of your C/m in this shot then you fail to cover the Queen, and the Queen is returned to the table. You must have pocketed at least one C/m to qualify to try to cover the Queen. If you win, you get bonus points if you were also the player to do this.

Answer (score -2):

If queen goes first, then the cover goes, then it is secured; otherwise you have to cover it.

Comment: Can you provide any reference for this as the other answer disagrees with this and does provide some reference.